# Content-type from fetch in locally run React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to front end dev. How can I set "application/json" content-type and gzip content-encoding in the fetch call in locally run React code?

```
const data = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: body,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json' // this does not work when run locally
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```js
const data = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(body), // this will encode body to string, assuming it's an Object
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

but I'm not sure what do you want with "gzip content-encoding". If the console prints any errors, they can be helpful too

Comment: body is already json string. I want to gzip the body.